# Hamachi Goes Offline

Tags: windows-server-2003, hamachi

I am running Server 2003 R2 and I have Hamachi installed.  When I log off of the server, Hamachi is no longer connected.  The Hamachi service is indeed started and seems to stay running, however from the Hamachi GUI, the server is RED.  How can I keep Hamachi running even though I am not logged in to the computer?

Comment: Looks like it isn't running as a service. Did you read this http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Running-Hamachi-2-as-Windows-Service/td-p/31377? I found it Googling for 'Hamachi service'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the answer to your question, which is quoted from the webpage linked below:

*So, in the hopes of converting more of you into paying customers, we’re making a small change to Hamachi: **unless a computer is part of a paid network, you need to be logged in and running the Hamachi UI on your desktop in order to allow it to function.** If no user is logged on to the computer then – even though the Hamachi service or daemon is active in the background – it will not go online in any networks that it may belong to. We believe this a fair change; if you’re using Hamachi casually (such as for gaming), then we’re glad to have you as a free user and this change does not affect you.*

If you are using the paid version, then you should not be having any difficulties -- otherwise you may need to contact them directly.

Full statement:
http://b.logme.in/2012/11/07/changes-to-hamachi-on-november-19th/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Paid for a subscription and BOOM it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply upgrading an existing network from free to standard did not do it for me. I had to create a new network and apply the subscription to it. This allowed all the clients to see the network as a paid one.